# SwiftUI macOS - Commands menu list is not updating to observable object changes

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I'm trying to list all recent used files (form observable object) in a menu bar list item but somehow the list only loads the values form the app model once the app launches and then never updates again.
To fix this I tried using a `@Published` variable, that gets updated as soon as the list changes, and a computed variable, that itself runs the update function, but in both cases the list stayed the same until the app is relaunched.
Somehow the variables are only read during the launch process and then never again.

My code:

```swift
@main
struct MyAPP: App {
    var model = appModell()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(appModell())
        }.commands { AppCommands(model: model) }
    }
}

struct AppCommands: Commands {
    @ObservedObject var model : appModell
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
            // list all recent used files
            Menu("Open Recent") {
                ForEach(model.getAllRecentUsedFiles, id: \.self) { file in
                    Button(action: { NSWorkspace.shared.open(file.location!) }, label: {
                        MenuButtonRecentUsedFile(type: file.type!, name: file.name!, icon: file.icon!)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


class appModell: ObservableObject {
   // @Published var getAllRecentUsedFiles : [fileInfo] = [fileInfo(), fileInfo()]
    var getAllRecentUsedFiles : [fileInfo] { getFileInfo() }
    ...
    func getFileInfo() -> [fileInfo] {...}
}
```

Is there a way to dynamically update the list using an app model?

Comment: have you tried using: `@StateObject var model = appModell()` in `MyAPP`

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't fix it, and I'm getting a purple warning telling me: "Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time.". Declaring it without @StateObjectworkes just fine, except for the Commands.

Comment: This looks like you're trying to work with documents. If you create a new Document App Project you'll get all the code to handle the recent documents.

Answer (score 0):

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct xxxApp: App {
    
    let appModel = AppModel.shared
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(appModel)
        }
        .commands {
            AppCommands()
        }
    }
}

class AppModel: ObservableObject {
    // singleton
    static let shared = AppModel()
    
    @Published var getAllRecentUsedFiles: [String] = []
    
    init() {
        self.getAllRecentUsedFiles = getFileInfo()
    }
    
    func getFileInfo() -> [String] {
        return ["File-01", "File-02"]
    }
}

struct AppCommands: Commands {
    
    
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
            Menu("Open Recent") {
                ForEach(AppModel.shared.getAllRecentUsedFiles, id: \.self) { file in
                    Button(action: {  }, label: {
                        Text(file)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, this fixes the purple error message but the list still loads the values only at launch time and doesn't update to changes. I don't understand why commands only reads the variable once not every time the menu item appears.