# Calling a function in an external SwiftUI View from a SwiftUI App menu .command

Tags: function, swiftui, menu

I am adding a 'New' File menu command to a SwiftUI macCatalyst app through the App menu `.commands` format as follows:

```
@main
struct ApptestApp: App {
    let myObject = MyObject()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
          .environmentObject(myObject) }
        .commands {
            CommandGroup(before: CommandGroupPlacement.newItem) {
                 Button(action:{
                    myObject.onAdd()
                }, label: {
                    // (2)
                    Text("New")
                })
                 .keyboardShortcut("n")
            }
        }
        
    }
```

by calling an `ObservableObject` defined in a new class as follows:

```
class MyObject: ObservableObject {        
    func onAdd() {            
        print("This is where the App menu item 'New' lands")
        // your code here
        
    }
}
```

My problem is I want to really call another existing onAdd() function shown below which is part of the main SwiftUI View, but I get an 'out of scope error' when I try to access that existing `onAdd()` function from the App `.command` menu.

```
public func onAdd() {
       
        if bulleton == true {
            
            items.append(Item(title: fullText, subtitle: fullText2, isExpanded: false,isChecked: false))
            
            saveNotes()
        } else {
            if bulleton == false {
                 items.append(Item(title: fullText, subtitle: fullText3, isExpanded: false,isChecked: false))
                Self.count = 1
                Self.count += 1
                Self.number += 1
                saveNotes()
            }
        }
    }
```

Question: How does one access an existing function in a main external SwiftUI View from the App menu `.command`?

Comment: It would be better to create a sperate `struct`/`class` that handles the logic behind this function & use it wherever you need.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the solution in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70916746/7421005):
You have to reference to the `MyObject` class via a **singleton**. This allows you to point to the very same object.

First, define the singleton in your class like this:

```swift
class MyObject: ObservableObject {
    // Define singleton
    static let shared = MyObject()

    func onAdd() {            
        // …
    }
}
```

Second, reference the singleton in your environment object:

```swift
@main
struct ApptestApp: App {
    @State private let myObject = MyObject.shared // reference singleton here

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(myObject)
        }
        .commands {
            // Coming up in next step …
        }
        
    }
}
```

Now you can reference to the singleton directly outside of the `@EnvironmentObject` like so:

```swift
CommandGroup(before: CommandGroupPlacement.newItem) {
    Button(action:{
        MyObject.shared.onAdd() // directly call singleton
    } label: {
        Text("New")
    }
    .keyboardShortcut("n")
}
```